# Is it good to use mongodb with asp.net or mysql for react-native apps?

Tags: java, web-applications

We have an ERD thats normalized and has a lot of foreign keys. The technology and database is entirely up to us. Since we are just students and are required to make **a mobile app + a web app with centralized data**, what tech-stack shall we use?

**APP Features**

- Cashless payment, user wallets, food ordering, QR scanner for check-ins

**What tech-stack to use**

1. React Native (mobile),ASP.NET (web), MongoDB
2. React Native (mobile),NodeJS (web), MongoDB
3. Java (mobile),ASP.NET (web), MYSql
4. any other?

Kindly suggest me the options based on our requirement, good resources and ease of development.

Comment: Opinion/etc questions are explicitly off-topic in SOs detailed in the FAQ. Your  problem statement largely answers the DB question—but realistically it just doesn’t matter what you use, delta doing the mobile app in Java means no iOS.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the question you have more foreign keys and complicated joining table so you can easily adapt with that feature with SQL so use MySQL .
 To connect and get the information from MySQL has more advanced features in java so you can use java for backend services.
For web development .Net will help you.

Comment: what if we use React Native with ASP.net along wiith Firebase?

Comment: In java we have lot of inbuilt functions so we don’t want to create some additional features.

Comment: No I mean if we use Google Firebase along with React Native app and ASP.NET. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Yes That’s also good option but my options is already answered because I worked on those technologies as well.